# Reduce firebase cloud firestore reads by using cache

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a web app using google firebase cloud firestore and Angular 8. I often use the same lists that are requested in different components. What is the best way to reduce the number of reads.

- **Cache**
  does firebase cloud firestore automatically use cache if the list is available in the cache memory?
  Currently I am using AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(), this takes the data out of cache memory if there is no internet connection. Is it also possible to get the data from cache even if there is an internet connection?
- **Save list as global variable**
  is it a good idea to store a list in a global variable? I would save the list that is requested for the first time in a global variable and when a list is requested for the second time use the global variable instead of retrieving the list from firestore.

What is the best solution or are there other solutions?

Comment: Hi, would be interesting to know how you solved this, could you share?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually configure in your get's options the source you want to use, not mattering if you are offline or not, the options are `'cache'`, `'default'` and `'server'` and you can get  more details on which suits better your needs in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Source), the usage is as you can see in the example in this [second documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options):

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
var getOptions = {
   source: 'cache'
};
docRef.get(getOptions).then(function(doc) {
   // Do something
})
```

Also, you can check [enabling offline data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline) to set properly sized cache.

I don't see much value in using a local copy of the list if you are using the cached option of firestore since they would basically do the same thing.

Comment: No, this didn't work for me. Currently I'm using this to recieve my data:

`itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;
  items: Observable<Item[]>;
getItems(){
    this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('items', ref => ref.orderBy('title', 'asc'));
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Item;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    }));
    return this.items;
  }`

Comment: You could do something like described in this [link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/pull/1813) which could be `this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges({ includeMetadataChanges: true }).pipe(filter(actions => actions.filter(a => a.payload.meta.fromCache === true)),map(changes => {...` or something similar, let me know if this helped

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm using global variables now.